# member.presence is undefined in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm setting up Slash Commands with my Discord.JS bot.

I have a `/rank` command in the XP/leveling portion of my bot, but when I check `interaction.member.presence` for displaying it in the rank card, it returns `null`.

I've tried to look up this problem and look through the documentation of Discord.JS, but nobody else seems to have had this problem yet and I don't see anything in the documentation or Discord.JS guide to help solve this problem.

Here is the `/rank` command:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const SQLite = require("better-sqlite3");
const sql = new SQLite('./mainDB.sqlite')
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const canvacord = require("canvacord");

module.exports = {
    name: 'rank',
    aliases: ['rank'],
    description: "Get your rank or another member's rank",
    cooldown: 3,
    category: "Leveling",
    async execute(interaction) {
        if(!interaction.isCommand()) return console.log("yes");

        await interaction.deferReply()
            .then(console.log("a"))
            .catch(console.error);

        let user = interaction.user;

        client.getScore = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?");
        client.setScore = sql.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO levels (id, user, guild, xp, level, totalXP) VALUES (@id, @user, @guild, @xp, @level, @totalXP);");



        const top10 = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE guild = ? ORDER BY totalXP").all(interaction.guild.id);
        let score = client.getScore.get(user.id, interaction.guild.id);
        if (!score) {
            return interaction.editReply(`This user does not have any XP yet!`)
        }
        const levelInfo = score.level
        const nextXP = levelInfo * 2 * 250 + 250
        const xpInfo = score.xp;
        const totalXP = score.totalXP
        let rank = top10.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.totalXP - a.totalXP
        });
        let ranking = rank.map(x => x.totalXP).indexOf(totalXP) + 1
        //if (!interaction.guild.me.hasPermission("ATTACH_FILES")) return interaction.editReply(`**Missing Permission**: ATTACH_FILES or MESSAGE ATTACHMENTS`);

        try {
            var cardBg = sql.prepare("SELECT bg FROM background WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?").get(user.id, message.guild.id).bg;
            var bgType = "IMAGE";
        } catch (e) {
            var cardBg = "#000000";
            var bgType = "COLOR";
        }

console.log(interaction.member.presence);
        const rankCard = new canvacord.Rank()
            .setAvatar(user.displayAvatarURL({
                format: "jpg"
            }))
            .setStatus(interaction.member.presence.status, true, 1)
            .setCurrentXP(xpInfo)
            .setRequiredXP(nextXP)
            .setProgressBar("#5AC0DE", "COLOR")
            .setUsername(user.username)
            .setDiscriminator(user.discriminator)
            .setRank(ranking)
            .setLevel(levelInfo)
            .setLevelColor("#5AC0DE")
            .renderEmojis(true)
            .setBackground(bgType, cardBg);

        rankCard.build()
            .then(data => {
                const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(data, "RankCard.png");
                return interaction.editReply({attachments: [attachment]});
            });

    }

}
```

Notes:

1. **I do have the Presence Intent enabled.**
2. Sorry if this seems like too little information. It's just what I
   know so far, and I can't think of anything that I can do about it.
3. I know this command is very messy. I'm not asking how to fix that.  I will fix that later.

Comment: I wonder why are you creating a new instance of `Discord.Client` inside of a command without the presence intent. You should probably pass the `client` as an argument to the `execute` function. Or access the client using `interaction.client`. I'm not sure if that is the issue tho.

Comment: I know that already. As I said in the post: "I know this command is very messy. I'm not asking how to fix that. I will fix that later."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have the **PRESENCE INTENT** enabled, you need to specify that you will be using the aforementioned intent in [`ClientOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions).

---

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES],
});
```

Comment: I updated the code, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Nevermind... I forgot to update it everywhere in the code. That is why I need to re-write the code so that it's not such a mess.

Comment: @SwxtchCode I'm glad you managed to fix it in the end. :)

Answer (score 1):

First You need to enable intent

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES
  ],
});
```

Now we need Create a var of member

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first()
```

For get the presence of members use [#presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence)

```js
console.log(member.presence)
```

Will get results as

```
Presence {
  userId: 'USER_ID',
  guild: [Guild],
  status: 'online',
  activities: [Array],
  clientStatus: [Object]
}
```

Comment: message.mentions.members.first()
on what event are you getting the user?

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return
  let member = message.mentions.members.first()
  console.log(member)
// doesnt work.!
})

Comment: can you share me a working code on gist please :)
i tried and am stuck, didnt work.